# updating to laravel 5.2 composer error

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5

I am updating to laravel 5.2. I removed the reference to `"illuminate/html": "^5.0@dev"` in my composer.json and added `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"` and ran composer update and it worked fine.

Then, as per the [update docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0) I updated the reference in the composer.json from `"laravel/framework": "5.1.*"` to `"laravel/framework": "5.2.*"` .

Then I ran composer update and I get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
 - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.12
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.11
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.10
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.9
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.8
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.7
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.6
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.5
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.4
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.3
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.2
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.1
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0
- Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.2.0-beta1
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.9 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html 5.1.x-dev requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.1 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.2 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.3 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.4 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.5 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.6 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.7 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.8 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- laravelcollective/html v5.1.9 requires illuminate/support 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.1.28], illuminate/support[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.6, v5.1.8].
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support 5.1.x-dev
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6
- don't install laravel/framework 5.2.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8
- Can only install one of: laravel/framework[5.2.x-dev, v5.1.28].
- Installation request for laravel/framework 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.2.x-dev, v5.2.0, v5.2.0-beta1, v5.2.1, v5.2.10, v5.2.11, v5.2.12, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4, v5.2.5, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.2.8, v5.2.9].
- Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.1.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[5.1.x-dev, v5.1.0, v5.1.1, v5.1.2, v5.1.3, v5.1.4, v5.1.5, v5.1.6, v5.1.7, v5.1.8, v5.1.9].
```

anyone know what the problem is and how to fix this?
Should I post more info like config/app.php and composer.json?

Answer (score 0):

had to make it `"laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*"` instead of `"laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"`